# How can we open new view at the same frame with split pane and button?

Tags: java, swing, view, jbutton, jsplitpane

I have a `JSplitPane` in Java Swing. One part of the split pane has buttons to open a new view. I want to open a new view on the other part of the split pane.

How can it be done?

Comment: The second `JPanel` of your `JSplitPane` uses the `CardLayout` to switch from one `JPanel` to another.  I'd probably just use a separate menu `JPanel` and display `JPanel` in the `JFrame's` `BorderLayout`, rather than a `JSplitPane`.  The Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps of creating Swing applications.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons need to have ActionListeners or Actions assigned. Inside these listeners create the new view and add it to the JSplitPane's other view.

If creating a new view takes too much time you need to perform the activities on a separate thread, releasing the Event Dispatching Thread that invoked your listener so the UI does not freeze.

Comment: I add Action Listeners etc but my view opened in new frame. I want to open same frame in other JSplitPane part. How can it be?

Comment: @user17236706 *but my view opened in new frame.* - well don't create a frame and add the panel to the 
 frame. Add the panel to the split pane. The point is your "view" should be a panel, not a frame. A frame is simply a container for other Swing components. Your code should NOT be extending JFrame.

Comment: camickr is right: JFrame is a top level component - it will always resemble a new window. You used the wrong component, and as that you did not add it to the JScrollPane. Try JLabel first, then increase and go for JPanel that will contain further components such as JLabel.